# system() function not working C++

Tags: c++, system

I'm currently following a tutorial created by thenewboston on youtube. I'm not following it word for word but close enough.

My simple program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h> /* memset */
#include <unistd.h> /* close */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(){
    using namespace std;
    cout << "Those who wander too far off the path of reality. Will be plunged into total Madness." << endl;
    cout << "                                                                                          - BinKill-Ethical" << endl;
    system("cls");
    return 0;

}
```

This is my first program in C++ that I've created. I know next to nothing but I'm not able to get the system() function to work.

Output: [image]

All except for `#include <iostream>` are suggestions from other stackoverflow posts to try and get this working. None have worked. I'm using G++ to compile, if that matters.

Comment: `system` isn't guaranteed any results as far as C++ is concerned. You don't have a `cls` command (Windows does by default and that's what the tutorial uses).

Comment: Use `system("cmd /c cls");`

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, Not Windows, judging by `<unistd.h>`.

Comment: @chris Ah, quite true. `system("clear");` perhaps.

Comment: `cls` is not an executable. how about printing the equivalent of `cls`? I believe it is `'\033[H\033[2J'`.

Comment: It is windows. The includes were other suggestions on this site. CaptainObvious's suggestion worked. Thanks!

Comment: Since you have output "cls: not found", it means your system() function is WORKING!

Comment: However the "CLS" was not.

Comment: This isn't a programming question but a DOS shell question: There is no executable "CLS", it is a shell command, which means you need to launch a shell (cmd.exe) with arguments to tell it to do "cls".

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Linux, you can use the following instead:

```
system("clear");
```

And assuming that you would like to clear the screen before printing, your code becomes like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h> /* memset */
#include <unistd.h> /* close */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(){
    using namespace std;
    system("clear");
    cout << "Those who wander too far off the path of reality. Will be plunged into total Madness." << endl;
    cout << "                                                                                          - BinKill-Ethical" << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `system` function is used to launch an executable that exists on the target platform. On the Windows platforms the `cls` command is built into the  shell and does not exist as a stand-along executable. This makes it impossible to clear the screen using just `system("cls")` since an executable named "cls" is not a standard part of Windows. You can still clear the screen on a default installation of Windows but you have to do it by launching the command shell.

```
system("cmd /c cls");
```

The `/c` option instructs the shell (`cmd`) to execute the command `cls` and then exit.

If you are writing your program specifically for Windows I suggest taking a look at the [console API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). If you are writing your application for multiple platforms I suggest taking a look at [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html). Both will allow you to clear the screen in a more programmatic approach instead of using just `system`.

Comment: Er, this is not correct. `system()` launches a _shell_, not just any executable. Hence `system("cls")` will work just fine (and always has on Windows systems).